# Connect LAN using dialup

Tags: networking, internet, lan

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. I have a LAN connection which requires dial up to enter user ID and password as provided by ISP.

Note that I don't have router/modem. In windows LAN works perfectly well.

I have tried the following methods:

1. Using the traditional network admin method shows connection established but there is no Internet connection
2. Using `gnome-ppp` results in:

   ```
   Cannot open modem
   ```
3. Using `pppconfig` & `pon`/`poff` states either this:

   ```
   dwarkesh@radhe:~$ pon dwarkesh
   dwarkesh@radhe:~$ plog
   Mar 11 23:33:41 radhe pppd[2858]: Plugin rp-pppoe.so loaded.
   Mar 11 23:33:41 radhe pppd[2858]: Plugin /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
   Mar 11 23:33:41 radhe pppd[2858]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
   ```

   or this:

   ```
   dwarkesh@radhe:~$ pon comcast
   dwarkesh@radhe:~$ plog
   Mar 11 23:39:19 radhe pppd[3107]: pppd 2.4.5 started by dwarkesh, uid 1000
   Mar 11 23:39:20 radhe chat[3109]: Can't get terminal parameters: Input/output error
   Mar 11 23:39:20 radhe pppd[3107]: Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/comcast finished (pid 3108), status = 0x2
   Mar 11 23:39:20 radhe pppd[3107]: Connect script failed
   Mar 11 23:39:21 radhe pppd[3107]: Exit.
   ```
4. Using `wvdialconf` & `wvdial`, which displays:

   ```
   Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
   ```

Comment: Please copy and paste terminal output into your question, select it, and press the `{}` button in the editor.